# How to update xamarin essentials preferences within the same app session

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've created a settings page within xamarin that works just fine to update preferences when the app restarts. The purpose of this is to change the language of the app according to the bool value saved by the preference. It works great between app sessions (closing and restarting the app). However, I can't seem to get it to update within the SAME app session. Example, you tap the switch and everything changes to spanish instantly without the app needing to restart.

**Settings.xaml**

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:SettingsViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="Accent">#74cee2</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout>
    <views:Header/>
    <Label Text="Change Lang"/>
    <Switch x:Name="LangSwitch" OnColor="#bbbbbb" ThumbColor="#74cee2" IsToggled="{Binding ChangeLang}" Toggled="LangSwitch_Toggled"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**Settings.xaml.cs (just to make sure i'm able to reach the switch toggled event)**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Settings : ContentPage
{
    public Settings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async void LangSwitch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("ok", "ok", "ok");
    }
}
```

**SettingsViewModel**

```
public class SettingsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public SettingsViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Settings";
    }

    public bool ChangeLang
    {
        get => Preferences.Get("ChangeLang", false);
        set
        {
            Preferences.Set("ChangeLang", value);
            OnPropertyChanged("ChangeLang");
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeViewModel (where the ChangeLang bool is used to determine data)**

```
public class HomeViewModel : SettingsViewModel
{
    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        if (ChangeLang == true)
        {
            Title = "NICU";
            secondaryTitle = "Spanish";
        }
        else
        {
            Title = "NICU";
            secondaryTitle = "English";
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseViewModel (if you were wondering)**

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string title = string.Empty;
    string secTitle = string.Empty;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref title, value); }
    }

    public string secondaryTitle
    {
        get { return secTitle; }
        set { SetProperty(ref secTitle, value); }
    }

    string logo = "logo.png";
    public string Logo
    {
        get { return logo; }
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "",
        Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**UPDATE**

Like Jason said in the comments just use messaging center.

```
public class HomeViewModel : SettingsViewModel
{
    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        setLang();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<BaseViewModel>(this, "lang", (sender) =>
        {
            setLang();
        });
    }

    void setLang()
    {
        if (ChangeLang == true)
        {
            Title = Preferences.Get("ChangeLang", false).ToString();
            secondaryTitle = "Spanish";
        }
        else
        {
            Title = Preferences.Get("ChangeLang", false).ToString();
            secondaryTitle = "English";
        }
    }
}
```

I moved the ChangLang bool to my BaseViewModel but here's the updated one.

```
public bool ChangeLang
    {
        get => Preferences.Get("ChangeLang", false);
        set
        {
            Preferences.Set("ChangeLang", value);
            OnPropertyChanged("ChangeLang");
            MessagingCenter.Send(this, "lang");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `HomeViewModel` is setting its properties in the constructor and doesn't have any mechanism to change those properties when the setting value is changed.

Comment: What mechanism can I use to update the value?

Comment: create a method that does it?  Then call that method when the Preference is updated

Comment: For a thorough example of changing culture: not just language, but also details such as how to display dates and numbers, see [Mastering Multilingual in Xamarin Forms](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/mastering-multilingual-in-xamarin-forms/).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks for your response but I'm not using a translator. The values will be set like the code above throughout the entire app

Comment: @Jason can you show me an example?

Comment: the simplest approach would be to use MessagingCenter

Comment: jonwa, now that you have working code, please add that code as an answer. Then in 48 hours, you can accept your own answer. So everyone will know the question has been answered. Thanks!